# HIVE: Exception: Partition Already Exists while ADDING a NEW Partition to an EXISTING EXTERNAL Table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn, hive-partitions

I am getting the below error when the application (java) tries to execute an 'ADD partition' after 'DROP partition IF EXISTS' command in Hive:-

"""
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. AlreadyExistsException(message:Partition already exists: Partition(values:[xxxx, yyyy, zzzz-zz-zz, tttttttt], dbName:<db_name>, tableName:<tbl_name>
"""

Sequence of commands executed:-
Thread A: USE <db_name>
Thread B: ALTER TABLE <tbl_name> DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION(`i_id` ='xxxx', `c_id` ='yyyy', `dt` ='zzzz-zz-zz', `time` ='tttttttt') PURGE
Thread C: ALTER TABLE <tbl_name> ADD PARTITION(`i_id` ='xxxx', `c_id` ='yyyy', `dt` ='zzzz-zz-zz', `time` ='tttttttt')

Note:-
-Cluster - 5 Mgr nodes (Hive deployed on 3 of them), 3 Utils and 30 DNs
-There are no signs of any latency issues in ambari-server alerts/logs during the timeframe when this error occurs.
-It is an EXTERNAL hive table
-This is a random occurrence (twice a week), associated with separate tables (not the same table everytime).

Would appreciate any Help to understand what might be causing this issue (Partition ALready Exists) and suggest if I need to look into any other logs to find out the reason behind this.

Comment: Why are you doing this in separate threads? Hive command may hang and your create partition sentence executed before DROP. Do it sequentially in a single thread, even better in a single command batch if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
a) Yes, these are run on separate threads but as per hive-server logs the commands got executed one after the other had finished without any overlap. Hence, I think contention issue is very unlikely the reason.
b) DROP Partition is executed only as a precautionary measure. Every day once the file arrives - there will be a new partition created based on the date.
c) I am guessing this could be caused due to Hive command while adding the new partition got hanged and retried. And while retrying it could have thrown this error.